# Return an array from an Ember computed property

Tags: arrays, ember.js, promise

I have two related models - Task and Requirement. Requirements can be one of 3 types (Part, Tool, Material). A Task can have several requirements including several of the same type.

```
Task A
    Requirement 1 (Part)
    Requirement 2 (Part)
    Requirement 3 (Tool)
    Requirement 4 (Material)
    Requirement 5 (Tool)
```

When viewing a single Task I want to group the list of requirements by type in a sort of summary view.

```
Task A
    Parts Requirements (2)
    Tooling Requirements (2)
    Materials Requirements (1)
```

I have a computedProperty mostly functioning in my TaskController but I can't seem to get it to return back the array of requirement summaries that I'm building. All the fixture data is setup properly for both models (I can iterate each requirement and show it in the template with no issues).

Here are the models

### Task model

```
App.Task = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr()
    requirements: DS.hasMany('requirement', { async: true})
});
```

### Requirement model

```
App.Requirement = DS.Model.extend({
    task_id: DS.belongsTo('task'),
    type: DS.attr(),
    description: DS.attr(),
    quantity: DS.attr()
})
```

Here is the controller:

### App.TaskController

```
App.TaskController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    requirementSummary: function () {
        var self = this,
            results = [];

        self.get('requirements').then(function(requirements) {

            var arrRequirements = requirements.get('content');

            var parts = {
                name: 'Parts',
                description: '',
                count: 0,
                css_class: 'fa-cog'
            },

            tools = {
                name: 'Tools',
                description: '',
                count: 0,
                css_class: 'fa-wrench'
            },

            materials = {
                name: 'Materials',
                description: '',
                count: 0,
                css_class: 'fa-tint'
            };

            arrRequirements.forEach(function (requirement) {
                if (requirement._data.name == 'Part') {
                    parts.description += requirement._data.description + ' (' + requirement._data.quantity + ')<br>';
                    parts.count++;
                } else if (requirement._data.name == 'Material') {
                    materials.description += requirement._data.description + ' (' + requirement._data.quantity + ')<br>';
                    materials.count++;
                } else if (requirement._data.name == 'Tooling') {
                    tools.description += requirement._data.description + ' (' + requirement._data.quantity + ')<br>';
                    tools.count++;
                }
            });

            if (parts.description !== '') {
                parts.description = parts.description.replace(/(<br>\s*)+$/);
            } else {
                parts.description = "No Parts requirements found";
            }

            if (materials.description !== '') {
                materials.description = materials.description.replace(/(<br>\s*)+$/);
            } else {
                materials.description = "No Materials requirements found";
            }

            if (tools.description !== '') {
                tools.description = tools.description.replace(/(<br>\s*)+$/);
            } else {
                tools.description = "No Tooling requirements found";
            }

            results.pushObject(parts);
            results.pushObject(tools);
            results.pushObject(materials);
        });

        return results;

    }.property()
});
```

Currently it returns back the empty results array because it is waiting on the `self.get` promise to fulfill. If I return the result of `self.get('requirements').then(...)` then it returns the promise, not the results array and Ember isn't happy because it's not an array. What I want is for it to return back the populated results array.

The closest question I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23206883/how-to-return-a-promise-composed-of-nested-models-in-emberjs-with-emberdata) but it either doesn't solve the issue or I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to be using `requirementSummary` using an observable pattern, or after it's finished resolving.

Additionally this is not required due to requirements already being an iterable field:

```
  var arrRequirements = requirements.get('content');
```

And you should be using a getter to get a property, not going to ._data.property

```
  requirement.get('description')
```

Add this to your `task` template and you should see it populate (asynchronously):

```
{{#each requirement in requirementSummary}}
   Name: {{requirement.name}} - Total: {{requirement.total}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: OK I've fixed the bits where I'm using the API incorrectly but I'm still a little fuzzy on the observable pattern. I've read up on the Observer part of Ember Guides but am unsure exactly how to move forward. I've added the #each block to my template but the {{else}} block is the only bit that ever renders. Do you have any good resources for the observable pattern or on how to wait for the promise to resolve?

Comment: Would you include your associated route, and fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

The routes all seem to be working as well as the fixtures - I can use `{{#each requirement in requirements}}` and list each individual requirement with no issues. Just having the problem of generating the summarized property and accessing it after it's computed.

### from routes/application_routes.js

```
this.resource( 'tasks', function () {
    this.resource( 'task', { path: ':task_id' }, function () {
       this.resource( 'task_requirements', { path: 'requirements' } );
    } );
} );
```

### from routes/task_routes.js

```
// List Tasks
App.TasksRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.find('task');
    }
});

// Task Detail Route
App.TaskRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('task', params.task_id);
    }
});

// Task Requirements Route
App.TaskRequirementsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function () {
        this.set('task', this.modelFor('task'));
    }
});
```

### Fixtures

```
// SAMPLE TASK FIXTURE.
App.Task.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Test Task #1",
        "description": "This is a test task. There are many like it but this one is mine.",
        "requirements": [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
    }
];

// SAMPLE REQUIREMENT FIXTURE
App.Requirement.FIXTURES = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "task_id": 1,
        "type": "Part",
        "description": "This is a Part requirement",
        "quantity": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "task_id": 1,
        "type": "Part",
        "description": "This is a Part requirement",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "task_id": 1,
        "type": "Material",
        "description": "This is a Material requirement",
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "task_id": 1,
        "type": "Tool",
        "description": "This is a Tooling requirement",
        "quantity": 1
    }
];
```