# How can I get the relationships of a resource in an Ember route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have this code in an Ember route:

```
let forum = this.store.findRecord('forum', 'main').then(function(forum) {
  console.log('FORUM:', forum);
  let categories = forum.get('categories');
  console.log('CATEGORIES:', categories);
});

return forum;
```

This console returns this:

> FORUM: Object { store: Object, _internalModel: Object, id: Getter,
>   currentState: Object, isError: false, adapterError: null, OWNER
>   [id=__ember1476462923058714220863537]: Object, _super: ROOT(), 2 more…
>   }
>
> CATEGORIES: undefined

Obvisouly, a request is made to `/forums/main`, but nothing after that. What is the role of `forum.get('categories')`? How am I supposed to get the relationships of a resource? Shouldn't that request `/forums/main/categories`?

Forum:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  language: DS.attr('string'),

  // Relationships
  categories: DS.hasMany('category', { async: true }),
});
```

Category:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  // Attributes
  name: DS.attr('string'),

  // Relationships
  forum: DS.belongsTo('forum', { async: true }),
  boards: DS.hasMany('board', { async: true })
});
```

Router (relevant part):

```
this.route('community', function() {
  this.route('players');
  this.route('forum', function() {
  });
});
```

Comment: There was more complex [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40032747/ember-2-filter-relationship-models-hasmany-belongsto-and-calculte-computed-p) on similar topic yesterday. You can try to check it out.

Comment: We'd also need your model definition in order to properly help you here. Mainly we'll need to know how your forum-categories relationship is defined.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: You're assigning `forum` to a promise that returns nothing. This will also not work if the record returns by `.findRecord('forum', 'main')` does not have an id of `main`, you will get duplicated records because Ember Data thinks it's a new record.

Comment: The request will only go to `/forums/main/categories` if you include a relationship link in your server API payload.

Comment: @locks There is a relationship link in my API payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch `categories` as you make a request to the `forum` (synchronous requests), the relationship between the `forum` and the `category` model needs to be correctly stablished:

*models/forum.js*

```
App.Forum = DS.Model.extend({
  categories: DS.hasMany('categories');
});
```

*models/category.js*

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
  forum: DS.belongsTo('forum', { async: false });
});
```

You may also want to get the `categories` once your promise is resolved. In this case, you can do something like this:

```
this.store.findRecord('forum', 'main').then((function(_this) {
  return function(forum) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify('forum: ' + forum));
    let categories = _this.store.find('category', forum.get('category_id'));
  };
})(this));
```

If you can, I encourage you to add more details (`router.js`, `models/forum`, `models/categories` files would help) about your scenario so I can try to to provide a more accurate answer. Ember version details can also help.

Meanwhile, [this discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/what-is-an-async-relationship-async-true-vs-async-false/4107) and [this guide](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/routing/asynchronous-routing/) may be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added details to my question.